# Display readme text from github api

Tags: javascript, encoding, readme

When hitting the API to get the readme for react here: `https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/readme`

I don't know what to do with the base64 encoded text in the `"content"` string.

Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the base64 to a human readable format, I guess.
Depending on the language you are using but in javacript:
`atob(content)`

Got it from here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript

As to why they send base64 encoded string, you might find a reason here : [What is the advantage of using Base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682949/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-base64-encoding)