# Why do we need to base64 encode images before transmitting?

Tags: php, http, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the use of base 64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-the-use-of-base-64-encoding)

I've seen many code fragments that base64 encode images before transmitting over HTTP protocol.

I am wondering why do we need it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary, but it enables you to embed images without performing additional HTTP requests (where, in some cases, it's not possible or permitted).

Comment: Using the data URI scheme, you mean?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia entry on [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

> The term Base64 refers to a specific
>   MIME content transfer encoding. It is
>   also used as a generic term for any
>   similar encoding scheme that encodes
>   binary data by treating it numerically
>   and translating it into a base 64
>   representation. The particular choice
>   of base is due to the history of
>   character set encoding: one can choose
>   a set of 64 characters that is both
>   part of the subset common to most
>   encodings, and also printable. This
>   combination leaves the data unlikely
>   to be modified in transit through
>   systems, such as email, which were
>   traditionally not 8-bit clean.

And specifically regarding HTTP:

> Base64 encoding can be helpful when
>   fairly lengthy identifying information
>   is used in an HTTP environment. For
>   example, a database persistence
>   framework for Java objects might use
>   Base64 encoding to encode a relatively
>   large unique id (generally 128-bit
>   UUIDs) into a string for use as an
>   HTTP parameter in HTTP forms or HTTP
>   GET URLs. Also, many applications need
>   to encode binary data in a way that is
>   convenient for inclusion in URLs,
>   including in hidden web form fields,
>   and Base64 is a convenient encoding to
>   render them in not only a compact way,
>   but in a relatively unreadable one
>   when trying to obscure the nature of
>   data from a casual human observer.

Comment: Your quote is great! But it doesn't explain why transfer images in base64?

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP protocol isn't guaranteed to be "8 bit clean", so it might mangle a binary stream.

Comment: can you please explain how can HTTP be not 8 bit clean? How will server know? Is it specified in request headers?

Comment: This is just wrong. You can send whatever in the HTTP body

Comment: @wic, can you show me where in the HTTP specification it guarantees that the connection is 8 bit clean, because I can't find it.

Comment: RFC 2616, Section 7.2 (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.7.2)

Comment: @Julian, I don't see any such guarantee there, or anywhere else in the document for that matter.  As a matter of fact, the Transfer-Encoding section appears to be there precisely *because* there is no such guarantee.

Comment: Well, you are mistaken. HTTP is 8 bit clean; the message body simply carries a set of OCTETs (7.2).

Comment: The default fallback encoding is `binary/octet-stream` (section 7.2.1). Anyway, this discussion is pretty academic since  99.9999% of all HTTP content is sent as binary anyway (standard or not).