# Python AES-256-CBC Encrypt to PHP Decrypt with openssl_decrypt return false

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes, php-8

I am encrypting data successfully in python and sending the url safe data to PHP.  When I try to decrypt the data with the `openssl_decrypt` PHP method it returns `false`. I have been reading for 2 days know searching for a solution with none of them solving my problem [there are 2 similar questions on this forum, but they did not help, [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051293/encrypt-data-with-python-decrypt-in-php), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317715/encrypting-aes-256-cbc-using-python-and-decrypting-using-php) ].

The encryption uses python3.8 and package [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import hashlib
import os
import secrets

BLOCK = 16
PADDING = '~'
iv = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
secretKey = secrets.token_urlsafe(32) # 32 bytes is used as AES 256 expects 256 bits
encoding = 'latin-1'
s = 'very secret data' # secret to be encrypted

k = hashlib.sha256(secretKey.encode(encoding)).hexdigest()[:32].encode(encoding) # key hashed and encoded
pad = s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
cipher = AES.new(key=k, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=hashlib.sha256(iv.encode(encoding)).hexdigest()[:16].encode(encoding)) # cipher object

encrypted_secret = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(cipher.encrypt(pad.encode(encoding)))
print("Key: ", secretKey, "\n", "IV:",iv, "\n", "Encrypted:", encrypted_secret.decode(encoding))
```

`Outputs[0]:`

```
Key:  cdLTCHW95FjHF6ESu2Rkm-90AUbzDBv71HrdshsEx3k 
 IV: b16ezD5O05EDNovsqLExUg 
 Encrypted: RJqA3-n6d7hmKgj7biiwUKD0SjRjm__4f42P06R-qO8=
```

*I decode the encrypted secret result because it is sent as a json encoded object and json`s encoder complains about byte objects in its midst.

Decrypting in PHP is less code (for tests I copy key and iv over, but the iv is newly created every time and the secret key is stored on different server):

```
$key = 'cdLTCHW95FjHF6ESu2Rkm-90AUbzDBv71HrdshsEx3k';
$iv = 'b16ezD5O05EDNovsqLExUg';
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$blocksize = 16;
$padwith = '~';
$decoded_secret = 'RJqA3-n6d7hmKgj7biiwUKD0SjRjm__4f42P06R-qO8='; // secret is sent as string

$hashKey = substr(hash('sha256', $key), 0, 32);
$iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv_hash = substr(hash('sha256', $iv), 0, $iv_len); // cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \\0

$decrypted_secret = openssl_decrypt($decoded_secret, $method, $hashKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv_hash);

$what = rtrim($decrypted_secret, $padwith);
var_dump($decrypted_secret, $what);
```

`Outputs[1]: bool(false) string(0) ""`

I have tried setting `utf-8` as encoding in python, decoding the encrypted string with `base64` in php,  changing block size to 32, not using `hashlib` on python side, but none of the changes gave the expected decrypted result.

Can someone please give me a clue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need two clues, so let's call it a holiday bonus :-)

- your data is in urlsafe-base64, but your php doesn't decode it, so it tries to decrypt entirely wrong data. php doesn't (AFAICS) directly support urlsafe, so you need to convert it; you can then decode it and pass to `openssl_decrypt`, or simply call `openssl_decrypt` *without* `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` because it defaults to (traditional aka MIME or PEM or PGP or XML) base64.
- your encryption doesn't use PKCS5/7 padding, but OpenSSL uses that by default, so your decryption fails. You need to use `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` which becomes in this case a no-op and then (as you already did) do the unpad yourself.

With either the uncommented or commented line in this code, it works:

```
<?php
$key = 'cdLTCHW95FjHF6ESu2Rkm-90AUbzDBv71HrdshsEx3k';
$iv = 'b16ezD5O05EDNovsqLExUg';
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$blocksize = 16; // not used
$padwith = '~';
$secret = 'RJqA3-n6d7hmKgj7biiwUKD0SjRjm__4f42P06R-qO8='; // secret is sent as string
$fixed_secret = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$secret);
$decoded_secret = base64_decode($fixed_secret); // maybe used

$hashKey = substr(hash('sha256', $key), 0, 32);
$iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv_hash = substr(hash('sha256', $iv), 0, $iv_len);

$decrypted_secret = openssl_decrypt($fixed_secret, $method, $hashKey, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv_hash);
//$decrypted_secret = openssl_decrypt($decoded_secret, $method, $hashKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA+OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv_hash);

$what = rtrim($decrypted_secret, $padwith);
var_dump($decrypted_secret, $what);
?>
->
string(32) "very secret data~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
string(16) "very secret data"
```