# What is the Difference between Decode and Decrypt?

Tags: encryption, decode, terminology

This decrypt and decode word is used by most of the people. 
But whenever i asked them about "what is the difference between decode and decrypt?"
No one is able to answer perfectly way that i wanted to hear.
Can i be clear about this?

Comment: Decoding does not require a 'secret' key to get back to the original state.

Comment: reffer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption

Comment: Decoding 'CA' to 'California' or 'Canada' does not require decryption but does require decoding.

Answer (score 6):

Encrypting and decrypting are used to hide something (a secret message), while encoding and decoding are used to bring an information into a specific form (e.g. to send it over an internet connection).

So *encryption* is part of cryptography and usually relies on a secret key. Only with this key one can decrypt the message read the original message.

An example for *encoding* is the URL to open a web page. In this URL some characters have a special meaning like the `?&` characters. If you want to pass those characters as a parameter you have to encode them, so the browser doesn't interpret them. The [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function is a good place to get more information.

Another good example for encoding is the UTF-8 standard. Surely you know the ASCII table, where you can represent 256 characters with one byte. The UTF-8 encoding allows us to represent much more characters, but of course, you cannot do this with a single byte. The UTF-8 encoding defines when to use 1 or 2 or 3 bytes, and how a reader can recognize those 3-byte characters.

Comment: Can I be more specific by an example?

Comment: NIT: ASCII only defines the values 0..127 :}