# Java String Encryption

Tags: java, encryption

So this is my first post, and I was looking for some help in encrypting a string. This is almost certainly way above my level, but I decided to take it on as a challenge. Anyway, to the code:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please type a string to be encoded: ");
    char input;
    input = keyboard.nextChar();
    System.out.println("Your string was: "+input);
```

So this is what I've got so far, just a few simple lines that take a string, and give it back to you. What I would like to know is:

1. Is this a good starting point to work from?
2. What steps should I take next to encode the string?

Comment: Encoding or encryption? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption and edit your post ...

Comment: You need to decide on an algorithm to use, and if it is really encryption (as opposed to encoding), then there also needs to be a key.

Comment: What did you reseach? There are countless tutorials easily found by googling

Answer (score -1):

Your code is a good start. However, I would declare input as a `String` and get the `.nextString` (so the user can type more than one character).

There are many, many, many ways to encrypt. Here are some possibilities you could try:

- If you are feeling **very** adventurous or want the top-of-the-line encryption method, you could research AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).
- I would recommend something simpler, such as the *Polyalphabetic Substitution Cipher* (more well-known as the Enigma). Although it may seem difficult, it is not very hard to do.
- If you are not experienced with cryptology, I would first try a simple subsitution cipher. Then, you can move on to more difficult encryption methods.

I am no cryptologist, but if you want to design your own encryption method, make sure it involves some sort of `key`, or password. You will also want to make sure that it can be decrypted easily as well.

Comment: His code isn't a good start, it literally only reads a character, it doesn't even read a string. OP's questions could easily have been answered himself by even doing a little bit of googling instead of coming straight here with code that doesn't even REMOTELY come close to doing what he wants

Comment: I addressed that in my answer. Also, his question is asking about encryption, not code.

Comment: All of this could have been found with a simple google search by OP. It is expected that people do some precursory research before coming here for help, which @FoxMod clearly has not done.