# What kind of encryption is this? Website cookies

Tags: encryption, encoding, decoding

is there anything to see what kind of Encryption/Encoding this is?
I already decoded the first part, but when you decode it it looks like its encoded again, but when you decode that it gives all kind of random stuff, does anyone know how to fix this?
They are from cookies of a site:

```
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
```

This is Base64 encoding but when you decode that you'll get this

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SP>0e.t|adfs3.0 prd mijnprd 20142015|0069132@rocdeleijgraaf.nl,0e.t|adfs3.0 prd mijnprd 20142015|0069132@rocdeleijgraaf.nl,130994960146064225,True,H9pUlMeoo2X5CLnbxu3HwdTkXouw3igJtHhywxh19s4kDEhZfJyNulCXTG6gLPtcYLP0DKiuj7Xe8L2lusJVFMxSNXASlURufdEOByyoub8SGFF9932T8sdH6gdW4tHQmAt+0E4anZmX5D5wTeE7+9KCOtP8tgZ5u70DhJNFj2Rp604zLbzqkD5NPYFxCyOUSNgpKr/heuLw8U7XViVUYbuUyMTYZmBXZOpD8I2Fzw+KtLdPE3CFmHlvvo7Z0m5/xxVkrHHrl0eK/Aj47g1n2Gt1anKFTi+ITNA0ga3dP35hFxjBrnBjUTTWCPL+D0zECDiCoIUDpcfHxG1LfwWbWw==,https://mijn.leijgraaf.nl/</SP>
```

When you try to decode that middle part i get all kind of random stuff, does anyone know what that is?

Comment: The cookie is from a service that is using [Active Directory Federation Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services) to provide single sign-on access to multiple websites. It's encrypted, so don't bother wasting your time on this unless you have the key. incidentally, you could probably spend your time more usefully by learning the [difference between **encoding** and **encryption**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4657416/1679849).