# How can i encrypt and decrypt images in java android

Tags: java, android, image, cryptography

I have some images in my device's SD card. Now I want to encrypt them and save them into a path. and in another time be able to decrypt them. need a clear way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: @David: i get image's bytes and convert them to string and encrypt the string and again convert it to byte array and saved it. but when i try to get image back it does not return image.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364
Small example how to use aes on java and c

Comment: Thanks @user3280437 but i need image encryption not text encryption.

Comment: AES can be used for images as well as for text ...

Comment: if your image is converted to string, text encryption is what you need. But if you want help you will have to show us what you tried, and the code of is not working (converting back string to data to image from what you said)

Comment: Convert those bytes to base64 string when encrypting/decrypting

Comment: this is my code.[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7170919c65b3cd521cb8b763488b04bc)

Comment: you don't encrypt the image. You are using a encoding algorithm. For the difference see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp: can you please help me how to solve it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the image encryption? I assume that you want to prevent that another application opens the image file. Is that correct? Please take a look at the This question already has an answer here link