# How to decrypt a base64 string =

Tags: base64

I have no idea how to decrypt this hash, there are 6 numbers in the hash of (0sulka7svV5t/2SCKN94ppVxjH8=), and there are 3 numbers in the hash less than the ones (ZeFBdgJKvi0=)

/sUdBvF7oewQxksYWyKrWN9Wiz0= 
ZeFBdgJKvi0= 
0sulka7svV5t/2SCKN94ppVxjH8= 
wvZogiIBwHI=

Is there any way that I can decrypt a base64 string (i.e. 0sulka7svV5t/2SCKN94ppVxjH8=) back to an integer? I have no idea how it is encrypted (key or method used)

Comment: The basic assumption of cryptanalysis is that you *know* the algorithm.

Comment: Your hashes are certainly not just Base64 encoded... there's at least one other encoding or encryption in play. Your first hash decodes to `Ӌ¥®½mÿ޸¦q`.

Comment: If it's encrypted, you can go backwards. If it's hashed, you can only compare hashes. In order to decrypt, you need to know the encryption method and if they are smart any salts used. If this is your own code you should be easily able to look at how it was encrypted to decrypt. If you don't know how it was done, well there is a reason you're not supposed to be able to decrypt it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing Decoding and Decrypting. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption) to understand the difference.

Base64 is an encoding, the strings you've posted are encoded.

You can DECODE the base64 values into bytes (so just a sequence of bits). And from there, you need to know what these bytes represent and what original encoding they were represented in, if you wish to convert them again to a legible format.

You can use websites like [this one](https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter) to convert between base64 and other representations. Yours definitely do not represent any valid ASCII or UTF-8 strings.