# JWT Token Issue

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I created a jwt token using java keystore public key an and io.jsonwebtoken library.
After generation i copy pasted the generated token in https://jwt.io website. It decoded my token without using private key.How come this is possible?

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(userName);
        claims.put("scopes", scopes);
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey)
                .compact();
```

Comment: signing != encryption

Comment: jwt payload is base64 encoded. Your private key is used to sign the jwt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If you can decode JWT how are they secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301557/if-you-can-decode-jwt-how-are-they-secure)

Comment: @All: How to encrpty the jwt token then? Is there any mechanism whihc jwt lib provides ?

Comment: if you really need encryption, look into JWE (encrypted JWT): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516

Comment: @BadDeveloper Why do you think that you should be encrypting your JWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JWT is only signed, not encrypted.  The main security feature of the incoming JWT is that it has a checksum/signature at the end.  Your Java program has the ability to verify that the checksum matches the actual content of the JWT (e.g. headers and claims).  If the checksum does *not* match, then the server will assume the JWT has been tampered with and reject it.  The main use of a JWT is not so much protecting critical information as it is about controlling authorization and authentication in your application.

Comment: Yes @Tim . I am expecting a brief reply from you.

Comment: @BadDeveloper [difference between encoding and encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption)