# How do I decode a text that I don't know how it was encoded

Tags: c#

I have a string that I'm trying to decode but I don't know how it was coded maybe someone could help me (They are pairs of double xy)

> 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

Comment: Isn't that the point of encoding - Only those who know how it's encoded can decode it?

Comment: yes that is the point of coding but maybe there is a pattern that lets you know what it is encoded in

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any possible solution

Comment: You might try decoding it as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The resulting binary data might be a collection of `double` value pairs. There are online tools that may help you experiment, e.g. [this](https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter) and [this](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) (which does `float`, but not `double`) and [this](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html).

Comment: @dvo: No, that's the point of encryption. Encoding serves a different purpose, often to represent a large character set within a smaller subset as in the case of Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't. Unless you're an expert cryptographer (even then it's a stretch), you will not decode it. That's the entire point of encryption.

Comment: Decoding may be fairly easy, for example the OP's data appears to use the character set employed by [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. Once you have the decoded data in hand you can begin to explore whether it contains reasonable values for common data types, e.g. IEEE double-precision floating point values. That is quite different from _decrypting_ or recovering values that have been _hashed_.

Comment: Encoding/decoding and encrypting/decrypting are not the same thing. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption