# How to create custom middleware for encrypt webapi response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Right now I am returning an encrypted response

```
(IActionResult)Ok(_encryptFunction.Encrypt(jsonResponse));
```

I want to return an encrypted response like

```
(IActionResult)Ok(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Reference [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: basically I need to override Ok() Object Result to return an encrypted response. So it is possible through middleware or action filter ? @Nkosi

Comment: Hey Vikas Shinde, check this code,I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use middleware, too.

```
 app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
            {
                context.Request.EnableRewind();
                Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

                try
                {
                    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        context.Response.Body = memStream;

                        await nextMiddleware();

                        memStream.Position = 0;
                        string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();


                        memStream.Position = 0;
                        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseBody);//Encrypt responseBody here
                        memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


                        memStream.Position = 0;

                        await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    context.Response.Body = originalBody;
                }
            });
```

This code just write encrypted data over simple data.It's better to clear simple data then write new encrypted data in Response body.

Comment: The provided answer shows how to do Encoding (which can be easily reversed), not Encrypting - please see the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption