# WSO2 API Manager, what is Authorization: Basic <long hex value>?

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to `WSO2 API Manager` `(APIM)` using version `1.9.1`. I am referring to  link : **https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Token+API**, in this link they've given curl command

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=
<password>&scope=<scope1> <scope2>" -H "Authorization: Basic 
SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh, 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

Now I am trying to understand above `curl` command in order to create `Junit` to map all these `headers` and `body` values to my Spring `RestTemplate` API's. I understand all parameters, but I don't understand below

```
Authorization: Basic 
    SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh
```

Could you please explain what is the use of it? What we called long hex string by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode above string(`SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh`) and decoded string is `IZsIi6HDbB5e8VKdZAnUi_fZ3f8a:Gm0bJ6oWV8fC5OQLLlC6jslACW8a`

Normally these strings are combined with colon(clientId:clientSecret) and encoded with base64. `IZsIi6HDbB5e8VKdZAnUi_fZ3f8a` is the client ID and `Gm0bJ6oWV8fC5OQLLlC6jslACW8a` is the client secret.

Usage of it:-
You are trying to take the access token using above curl command. when you use above grant type, you have to provide client id and client secret to get access token.

Comment: SVpzSWk2SERiQjVlOFZLZFpBblVpX2ZaM2Y4YTpHbTBiSjZvV1Y4ZkM1T1FMTGxDNmpzbEFDVzhh - What we usually call this as UserAuth value ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood (by reading the same doc) that is **base64 encoded string**

And it also says that it "Combine the consumer key and consumer secret keys in the format consumer-key:consumer-secret and encode the combined string using base64."

You can get more info regarding this on http://base64encode.org and [What is base 64 encoding used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)