# Can a rawbytes image be reduced in size and converted to be stored on a database?

Tags: javascript, image, temenos-quantum, rawbytestring

I've been making the create account and edit profile page for a kony app.  The information of the created server is stored on a server.

My problem is, the profile picture that is captured by the phone or imported from the gallery is much bigger than it has to be.  Is there a way to reduce the image size so that it's not such a heavy load to upload on creating an account?

Kony uses javascript as it's code behind so if there is a way using javascript I would really appreciate that.

I currently have the image available in rawbytes and then I convert it to base64 so that it can be stored on the database.  So I need to reduce its size somehow to make the account creation and update process run more smoothly.  Possibly may need to store it in some other format.

Comment: Images are already compressed.  Images can be resized (to a smaller number of pixels) or they can use a more lossy compression which reduces the quality of the image.  Either will make the resulting image data smaller.  Also, base64 is not an efficient storage mechanism at all.  Are you sure you cannot store binary data in your database?

Comment: did you try a search for `resize image javascript`? Should give you plenty of reading

Comment: Ok I didn't know that, I've edited the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 ,  I most likely can store the image as binary data on the db, I'm just not sure how that's done (function to convert from rawBytes to binary)

Comment: I would presume that `rawbytes === binary` already.  What exactly do you mean when you say `rawbytes`?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know that either...

Comment: Base64 encoding makes the data larger, so if you can store the binary data you already have that will be a savings right there.

Comment: Did some more looking up about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for

Comment: After learning how to approach this problem I've asked a more specific question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989218/resize-an-image-file-size-in-kony-visualizer