# How do you apply patch file downloaded from gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

In Gerrit, under the download section for a change, there is a section that allows you to download the Patch-File:

[image]

Using `git apply` results in:

```
$ git apply 441eb56b.diff.base64
fatal: unrecognized input
```

What command do I use to apply this patch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
base64 --decode c6a9dcdb.diff.base64 > c6a9dcdb.diff
git apply c6a9dcdb.diff
```

(Replace c6a9dcdb with whatever abbreviated commit hash Gerrit gave you.)

Answer (score 8):

Here are possible solutions.

1. Just copy and paste `Cherry Pick`'s command.
2. Just copy and paste `Checkout`'s command, and run `git format-patch -1` to create the patch which can be used in `git am` or `git apply`. You could also run `git diff HEAD^..HEAD > xxx.patch` to generate a patch, which can be used in `git apply`.
3. Download the diff.zip, unzip it, `git apply` it.
4. Download the diff.base64, decode it, `git apply` it.
5. Run the `git fetch` part in `Checkout` or `Cherry Pick` commands, use `git merge`,`git rebase`,`git cherry-pick` or any command that can manipulates commits to apply the patch you need.
6. If the patch is to be applied to another branch which can be found in Gerrit, use `cherry-pick` button to do it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a base64 encode file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)). You need to decode the file first (see [here](https://www.base64decode.org/)). I think it's easier to use the Cherry Pick method instead.

Comment: Yeah, i ended up cherry picking the change. But that is very interesting about the patch data.

Comment: You could of course pipe the base64 decode result into `git apply`. But anyhow, the download-patch functionality appears to be primarily for people who don't have a checked-out git repo availabe, in which case the cherry-pick is of course easier. See [bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=302). What I miss is a patch download that really downloads only the diff between patchsets so that a cherry-pick won't interfere with my changes to the same patchset.