# How to display binary data as image in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am receiving a bindata from the Nodejs server and now from that I need to display an image.

How can I achieve this? Is there any method to convert bindata to JPEG or any other format? Or is it possible to convert that in server and then send that image to react?

Here's how I'm trying to display the binary data (`item.Image.data.data`) with an image tag:

```
<img src={item.Image.data.data} />
```

---

This is my detailed react code snippet:

```
componentDidMount(){
  let self = this;
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      self.setState({post:data.data});
    });
}

<ul className="w3-ul w3-card-4 w3-light-grey">
  { this.state.post.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Link  to="/displaylist" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} key={index}>
        <li className=" w3-hover-green w3-padding-16" onClick={this.handleClick(item.Id)}>
          <img src={item.Image.data.data} className="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" width="60px" height="40px" />
          <span>{item.Firstname}</span><br/><br/>
        </li>
      </Link>
      )}
  )}
</ul>
```

This is my nodejs code snippet:

```
server.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    databaseInterface.listStudent(function(err, students) {
      var myJSON = students;

      res.json(myJSON);
      // You should see the newly saved student here
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean your image is in base64 string format?

Comment: yes like series of characters.

Comment: Do u know how to achieve that?

Comment: have you tried the suggestion below? `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{binary data}" />` I think this should work

Comment: Yes i have tried both. But i am getting error like this : GET data:image/jpeg;base64,{item.Image.data.data} for using this <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{binary data}" />

Comment: i tried second one also i.e react-image-file but it won't give any error instead its not displaying image itself

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**If the binary data is represented as a *base64* string**:

```js
// Base64 string data
const data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAABSCAYAAADQDhNSAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAFN5JREFUeJztnHl0FFW+xz/VS3rLTkJ2EkICIWEzgICIw8Ao6KCo4zDKuM04bqjPJyLqoAj6VBREHcVtBnXUcUMU3BVUhFFQQJEQkwhJyJ6Qfe10ernzRzVFd9JJukOKd857+Z6Tc6qr7vKrb27d+t3f73tLSk1NFQxBNWj+tw34v44hglXGEMEqY4hglTFEsMoYIlhlDBGsMoYIVhlDBKuMIYJVhu6UdxgaTsSkGZjiRoBGg62umtZfDtFRcliV/szJaYSMHo8hKhZcLqxVpTQe2I2jpUmV/rrjlBGsMZpJ/fPtxJ27CI0+qMd1a3U5NdvepfLDN7A3N5xUX/rwSOJ/exkxZ1+MKTaxx3WXvYuqT96m6MXHcHV2nFRf/UE6FcEeXXAoEx95heBRY/st6+y0UrHlFUrfeg6nNbCb15rMjPjDDSRceCVao6nf8m2Fefx011U4WpsD6icQnBKCx61+jmHTfg2AEIKW3P005exFOJ2YEpKJmDidoMhorzq2ump+eeo+Gr7b4VcfkdNmM/qW1fJU4IYQAntjHY0/7cFaUYKk1RI+fiphWZNBkgCo/24Hh+67fnBu1AdUJzhy6q8Y/8ALAAiXk/x1d3Hsy/e7WaEhcsoskhZdR/j4KcppIQRVH79F4fMP4eqy+Wxfozcw6oa/EnfeH5DcpAkhaD60n7K3X6Bh3y4QLq86w+dcQMayNUgaLQA5K6+j4fuvB+uWvaCNiIhYpUrLbqQtuRdTfDIIQfm7L1O++UUfpQTWyhJqtr1LW2EeoZmnobOEIEkSIaPHETnlLBr27cTZ0eZVyxAdx4SHXiRq+hwkSUIIga22ioLH7qL4xXVYK0uAnuOnvbgArclCWGY2APqQ8J7/9EGCqm6a1hxM+KQZALicTsre+Ue/dep3f8G+6xdQ/fm7IGRyQtKzyH5yE8Hp45RywenjyH5yEyHpWYA8amu2vce+6xdQv/uLfvspe2cjLocDgPBJM9CagwO+P3+gKsGhYyag0cmOSkv+AexN9X7Vc1rbKVh/N/nr71amhqDIaCY9+grhp51B+GlnMOnRV5R529llo2D93RSsvxuntd2vPuxN9bTkHwBAo9MROmZCoLfnF1R108wjRinHbYdzA65fs+09OsqKGbfqGYLCh6E1WRi/+jkANEEGALqa6sldtUQhKxC0HT5E+Lgpiq2NP34bcBv9QdURHBQ5XDnuPFY5oDZa8w9wYOlldFaXAzKxx8ntrC7nwNLLBkSubFOVT1sHE+rOwSazctz9BRUIrJUlFL20vsf5opfWu19kA4OnTZ62DibUjUW43SZAeWENBObkdEbfsqrH+dG3rMKcnD7gdr1s8rR1EKEqwZ6+q9Y4sBESFBHF+AdeQBccCoCtoRZbQy0grxDHP/AC+oioAbXtOWp787NPFqoS7LkE1YdFBFxf0geRtXIDxuHxcnvtbeSs+As5K/6Co11+vI3D4xm3cgOSj/hGf9CHnrBJreWyqgTb6muUY0N0bB8lfSP9ppWEjp0EgHA6+PnBW2kvzqe9OJ+fH7wV4ZT92NCxk0i/6b6A2/e0ydPWwYSqBB9/8wPyai4AxM67hLj5vwfkRUTh82to/OHfyvXGH/5N4QtrlN9x8y8hdt4lAfVhik9R2ve0dTChKsEdZYXKsTnF/5eROSWdtCX3Au4V2vYtVLz/ao9yFVtfpXrbe8rvtCX3BthPmk9bBxOqLjTsTQ3YGmoxREajDw7DGJtEZ3VZr+X1YZEYomLIuGMtWoNRPuly4WhvYdT1f0XS6ZE08pgQLhfCYcfR3opwOpG0WrQGI5l3PU7+2juw1dX0GVc2xiahDw4DoKuxDnvTycWge4PqAffWX3IwTJ8DyHNl57EKzEmjCB41FktKOuakUZgSkjHGJKA19IzhSlotiRde5Xd/lpR0Jm/YAoDTZqWzpgJrRQkdZYW0Hz1MW2EeHWWFytx+3Ea1oHq4MmnRtaT+eRkgu1g6k0U1p95fOK0dOKztGNyxjKKN6yjb9HdV+lKFYI3RxLDpc4ieeQ4Rk89E10+kSgihxHKPo6Ugh5bc/TjaW3F2duDqsuGyd52I7UoaNPogNEEGtEYzOksIoVmTCR0zvs92fcHR0Ubj/n9T+83n1O/5ElenNfCb7gWDSnDI6PHEL7iM6Fnz0ZosPsscf2O3HcmlrSifjtIjdJQfJeH8xcQvWAyAvbmRvdedF3BuTh8WydQXPlZ87soP36Dig39hTkzBPCKd4NQxBKdlYYxN7JV4p7Wd2l2fUvnhG4MydQwKwRHZM0levISwcVN6XBNC4LJ1Kjmyo6/8jZLXN3iVsaRmMPmpzUhaHUII8tcuH3AAfPicCxi7fK3ct9PB/lt+R3tRvleZ5MU3kXLlfwFyDlBrMPpcKjcf2kfJ68/Q+MM3A7IFTjKjYUpMJfOux0i5/BZltQUyqW2FeVS8+xKHn15N6+EcomfNB0BjMFL96SavdrLufQpjTAIAjft2UfziuoGaRHtxAaFjJmJKSEbSaLCMHEP1Z5u9yqRecweGqFj5n7luOUUvPkZXXTW60AhlXgZ5lRgzdyFhmZNpKcjB0dIYsD0DHsGJF1/NyKuXKqFDAKetk5ovtlL54eteo0ZrsjDjzW/RGowIIfj+T2cr7prniHPaOtl3/W9P2uk3xiYy5fmPFFcv79E7lCfCGJvE6S9tQ5IknLZOdl96hleQ3pKaQfyCxcTMXXjCVUSOVRS/vJ7yd18OyJaAR7Ck0zN2+VqSfncNklb28lz2Liref5Wf/+dWar/+CHtjnVcd4bDLbllyGpIk4WhtpjnnezQGI+PuewadJRghBKVvPkf9t9t9G2qyEDVjLtGz5hE+4XSCwodhq61COOw9yjraWpC0OsInTgMgdPQEKj9+E+F0kLDwSiLc5+t3b+8xFdkb62j47iuqPn0HSaslOC0TSatF0uqInDwLc+JI6vd8BS5Xj3592h0QwRoNWfc8pTzucvZ2Hzn3XMuxrz7sU8ThsncxfPYCAAwxCVRsfZWk319L1Bm/AeQ0fd7DS5X4gicSLrqKcaueJWbuQsInTiN84jSizzqX+PMX47J30eoj4N5acJCYuReis4SgswTj6rLRnLufMUsfRh8cihCC4pfWYy0v9m1vZ4fsWez8BEtqhjKFWVJGYxk5htpdn/gVgg2I4JQrbyX+3EWATG7Zpr+Tv+5Ov+amzqoy4s5dhNZkQR8cirXiKCOvvg1NkAEhBEc23E/bkZ5ppfSbV5G8eInXVHQcmiADkVNmERQeRcP3O7yuCacDe3MD0TPPAeTEqe1YFXHz5XiFvbGOw0+v7pHS7w5HaxM1X2xBow8iNDMbSZIwJ6UiabQ0/bSn3/v2m2BT4kgy73oMSaNBCMHRV56k5NW/+R9IFy70oeGKpzHs9F8pC472onyOPHN/jyrDZy8g9c+399t0yOjxWMuP0n70F6/z7Ud/IWrGXIIio9EEGRh2+q+Uaa1i62s0/uindyAETT/uRricREyaDkBY5mkc2/lJvxo3v4M9CQuvUIxr3LeL0jee9beqgsqP30I4nXLH7hEphKD4n4/7/EclL17id9s+ywpB8cuPKz+VPp1OKj9+MxDTASh941nq98oCFUmrI2HhFf3W8ZvgiOyZsnFCUPLGMwEbB2CrqaBuj7dmoTX/J5+qGmNskldWuj+YR4zC6EPo17D3a1ryvOfouj1fYBtgEtZzYB3npC/4TbAxOk45bi0Y+Aqn8oPXvX6XbfItRjEMj/N5vi8YPHzxvvrobkMgaC3IQbifNmO07/484TfBTvf6XJIkdCFhAzQPgtMyvX6HZEz0Wc5l6wyoXXnF6DuG0L2PkLSsgNr2hC4kTFlmO/2QvvpNcFtRnnJ83N0KGBotCRd4z1sJ5y9GHxbZo2h7yeGAEpHC3kV7yZEe5/VhkSScv9jrXPwFl4Nb+Bcohs/+rXLsyUlv8JvgY19+oBwn//EmjDE957v+EDVjDsZuj77WZCFp0XU9yro6rRz7+iO/2z729Uc+o2BJi67rEXgyDo8jasYcv9tW6sUkkvzHmwH5ifHkpDf4TXDNF1tod8v89SFhTHhoY69zXm+IO+9S5bjxwG7lOOH8xT7bKn5pPV3dVoW+0NVYR7EPYYohOk4ZvUIIrz49bfEHhuHxTHhoI3r39NhReoSaL7b0W89vgoXTSd6a2xXVuSkhhewnN/n1JgV59RZx2hkAuBx28h9ZRtPB72UjggyMvPq2HnW6Gmo5uOIaOmurelwDd+iztoqDK66hy62V8IRnrKQ5Zy/5jyzD5V5aR5x2Bgb36qw/RGTPJPvJTZgSUgA5YJ+3ZpnicvaFgFZy9qZ6Wn45SPSZ89Do9GhNZobPuQBjbCKtBT/1KflPWHgFEW4pa/2eL6n+7B06SguJnf97JEnCkpJOw75ddHVLn9sb66j+7B1cXTb04cPQh4aBEHSUFlH5wb/IX3unT5crZMwE0m5coeiG8x6+DWt5MSFpmZiTRiFJEvbWJppz9vZqc1BkNGlLVpJ67Z3o3NOMs9PKofuX0Jrnnx5uQNG04PQssu592itE6ey0Uvnxm1S8909sPkbc1L9/gjkpFSEEufffpGh4M+5cR8yvzwegpeAgP/73or5XhxqNfL2vMpLEaU+8rUhSa776gPxH5LTVsBlzGXef7Md3lBWx99pze1Q3RMeRcNFVxJ93qRLHPi7uzn3g5oCUogNK27cdzmX/jQup3vae4hNqjSaSLv4T017eTtbKDQybPhdJpwfAMnIM5qRUQI50NezdqbRVvHGd4u6EjplA3PxFfXfucvW7PI+bv0gh19nZQfHGE/Hlhr07sbtVPOakVCwjxwBylHDY9LlkrdzAtJe3k3Txn7zIrdm+hf03LgxYhnvSGY3QrMmkXrNMkeN7wt7WQsN3X6EJMigRuOrPN1Ow/q9e5UZcej0jr14q12ltltNFfrzcfEEfESWnjULC5JjJy49T+tbzXmXGLH2I2HN+B0Dtrk9xddmInPZr9G7923EIIWjJ+5Gijetoyd0/IHtOeo+GrbaK6s8203xoP/rQCExxIxRHXBtkIDg1A0vyCYFHV2O9PC+6nPJIEoKW/INEnTmPoLBItAYjxthEand+MiB7MpatUbYVdJQVkb/uTnnUa7SYR4wicsosQjOzFaWRJTmN4NQMtB7ROuFy0bB3J4efXsXRfz7hc8rzF4OeVTbGJBLzmwsZPnsB5qSRfZZ1dXXRUVGMtbwYXXCo4mUA5D92N3XffC5nG/qL2EmSHJCfeTYZt5+QUzX++C2OthZMiSMxJ4xEE9S7QFAIgbW8mGM7PqJm+3t01lT4d8P9QFVdhDklneRLb/Ra/QQK4XLhsllxdtkQdjvCJbtGkkaLpNejDTKgMZgUxc9AcGzHR5S8+SwdRwd/O6+qyp6Oo4ext56Il1Z9uglrZSkh6VkEj8qU0+f9ECNpNGhNll5lAP5AuL2Ozupy2gp/pvVwLqb4EYq40N7apAq5cAqkU6EZbvmp+03cfGifck1jMGFOTMGUkIIxJhHD8DgMUbEMO302klar1OsPnhoH4XRS//0ObHXV2I5V0VlTjrXiKB3lR72CQWHjpigEH7dRDahKsKTTYUkZLf9wuWjt5uK4bFbaCvNoK/QOmiRffgspl9+s1MtZeT0t+QfQ6PUguUe8cOGy2wkdO4nxq59H0mrdsepnKXntqX5taz2cq4gGLSmjkXQ6hKNnPvBkoap81ZQwUiYFeSNLb+HE7ih5fYOyjJa0WjKWrUFnsmBvasDeWCf/NTWgM1nIuH2NMtqbc/b2ELX0BpfNqmyg0ej1mBL6fiEPFCoTfEJ03VFW5H9Fl4u8NUuV+EJQRBRZ921A46FT0BiMZN23gSD3/oyuhlry1iz1O50O0FF+wiZPWwcTqhLsmQXprAlMTNLVUEvug7cqwZmQ9HFkLF8rS5wkiYw71hLi3lrrctjJffBWnwGfvtBZdcImT1sHE6oSrA8fphwHevMALbn7OfL0/YofHD3zHNJuWEHaDSuIPlNOxx9P+Q9kpdXVeMImT1sHE6q+5HTmE66Vo611QG1Uffo2psQUki65BsArkyuEoHzzi1R98vaA2na0n7BJax64G9gX1N2IqD3x/3M5e0qc/EXRxrUc2/Gh1zkhBLVff0zRxrUDbtdTdiVp1RlrqhIs7CduwNd3evxvSNDRTeIkSZL8kjqJHaSee+uEvWvA7fQFdTfBeEiqgsIGOMdJEqOuu4vEi67ucSnl8lvQWULk7VwDINrTJrtKX6FSlWDPgMnxeHAg0BjNZNzxiKIvE0LQuG8XAJFTzwIg8aKrMQxPIH/t8oC/IOVp02AFd7pD1Smi7cjPynHY+KmA/xuuzUmjyH7ibS9ya3d8xKHVSzi0eonXnBw982yyn3gbc5L/SiAkyW2TWzDuYetgQt2NiKVHsNVVA2CIiiFi8pn9V5I0JCy8guynNmNxbyoUQlD61vPkPboM4bAjHHbyHllGyZvPKbEKS0o62U9tlr0Mqf/bisg+E0NUDABd9TV0lPbUVAwGVP8oki40QvmqSHB6JjXbt/oUTQOET5xO5ooniJt3CRp3usnR0U7BuuVUbu2507PpwB46ygqJmDxL3nGk0xM59SyGTZuNtbK018WN1mQh854nCXILXiref42mA/1LUQcC1ffJ6cMiOX3jZ8rnCNoK8yj8xyM05+xDuJyYYpOIyJ5JzNkXeX03RwhBa8FB8h+9o9+Pbpjik8lYvpbQbhKploKD1Gx7j8YfvsFaXYak0RI2fiqj/rJc+Uieo62F76+Zd9JfG+wNp+TDdNGz5jP27se9Yr/HY7S+4sGO9laOvvY0FVtf8T+2oNGQsPBKUi6/GZ0lpMdl4XKBJHmHNl0u8h6+jdpdnwZ+U35C9SkC5LnYWl1O5OQzlUdf6n6zQuC0tlOx9VXyHr6NpgO7A3O9hKA1/wDVn70DkoQlZbSX7929P2enlYIn7qF2h//yrIHglIzg4zBEx5Fw4VVETj1L/vqqJNFVX0PrLznUf7eDum8+C/h7lb1BazITNXMew6bNJmT0eIKGxYAQWKtKadi7k4otvvUbg41TSvD/Rwx9oFllDBGsMoYIVhlDBKuMIYJVxhDBKmOIYJXxH4r7WLwgFoGBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'

const Example = ({ data }) => <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`} />

ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**If you just have an image URL, you can simply do**:

```js
const imageURL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1280px-React-icon.svg.png'

const Example = ({ imageURL }) =>  <img src={imageURL} width={100} />

ReactDOM.render(<Example imageURL={imageURL} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I am still getting error like : GET data:image/jpeg;base64,{item.Image.data.data} for using this <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{binary data}" />

Comment: Jordan it's not working.. Please tell me where i am going wrong and please help me out to achieve that..

Comment: @AbhilashMuttalli I've added React example. You can check it.

Comment: Make sure your image is properly encoded. For instance in base64. Here is described why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for

Comment: You're welcome! I'm really happy that I helped you! :)

Comment: And what if the binary data is literally binary data? E.g. it got sent over via a websocket and it's just a UInt8Array? Converting to base64 of blob is rather expensive, especially if you're running a (low framerate) equivalent of a frame server.

Answer (score 35):

If you need to display binary image from api, and the binary data look like this `����JFIF��� ���` 
convert to blob first and use `URL.createObjectUrl(BLOB);`

1. using axios, add `{responseType: 'blob'}` to the config

or

2. using fetch api, `response.blob();`

display image from blob
`<img src={URL.createObjectURL(responseData)} />`

I don't know is this the best solution or not, but it works.

Comment: this is the answer for that JFIF response

Comment: in number 1, using axios, add `{responseType: 'blob'}` to the config, 
I have code like this
` return axios.post(`${API_MOBILE}/${path}`, formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })`
did I should put `{responseType: 'blob'} inside `return.axios()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748564/how-to-convert-data-binary-into-image-in-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment110964426_62748564
here my question, please come and give some suggestion for me please

Answer (score 17):

If you get the data as

### 1) Base64 Encoded string

It will look like `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...`

Then just prepend ***data:image/jpeg;base64,*** or ***data:image/png;base64,*** as per your filetype on the src value.

### 2) Non Base64 Encoded string

The data of response will look like ����JFIF��� ���

In that case, use **responseType: "arraybuffer"** in the request

and we will get the response as arrayBuffer which can then be converted to base64 string and later you can prepend the ***data:image/jpeg;base64,*** when you use it as the src of an img tag.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587064/6707951

Answer (score -4):

You can simply concatenate your variable with server path:

```
<img src={`http://yourip${cat.path}`} width="100px" height="100px" />

<img src={`${serverUrl}${cat.path}`} width="100px" height="100px" />
```

This is working very well for me, hope this will help you!