# How to view doc based on base64 in react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, pdf, base64

```
let imgsrc = this.state.retrieveuploadfile.filecontent; 

<Dialog
    className=""
    open={this.state.openattachmentDialog}
    modal={false}
    autoScrollBodyContent={true}
    contentStyle={{ maxWidth: 'none' }}
    onRequestClose={this._closeDialog} >
    <div>   
        <img src={"data:image/jpeg;" + imageBase64} style={{maxWidth: '250px', margin: '15px'}}/>
                  <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src={"data:application/pdf;" + imageBase64} />
    </div>   
</Dialog>
```

I have a dialog where i can list out all the attachments which are uploaded.
After the successful upload of an image I am calling the Retrieve API for all uploaded images. I am receiving the response in the below format

If it is an image I need to show the image, if it's a PDF I need to show the PDF.if it's a Word I need to show the Word.
Based on base64 we need to convert and show them in the UI.

You can see in the response in the `filecontent` property the base64 code.

How can I show a word based on base64 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-image-in-react)

Comment: @AswinRamesh my question is not only image same like image if i the base64 is pdf file how to fetch that