# ReactJs: how can i render binary (base64) image format

Tags: reactjs, base64

i have images in sqlserver as a binary, how can i display them in reactJs?

i tried the following but doesn't work

```
<Image source={{ uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${results.student_photo}` }} />
```

i also tried

```
const base64Image = {results.student_photo};
<Image source={{uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Image}`}} />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display binary data as image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

This may answer your question.

> [How to display binary data as image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried that thaks i displayed it in angular easy, but react is a bit different