# How to Render Binary Data in Image in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, expo

Help!!! I am currently struggling to render binary data as an image in react native. I am receiving an array of numbers from the backend, and I have no clue what to do with it in order to render it. I'm not sure if I need to convert it into base64, and if so, how to do it, or if I can simply display the raw binary data without base64 processing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337254/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react-native) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the binary data for image you should append this at the beginning of the data received: `'data:image/png;base64,'`

So basically,

```
<Image style={{width: 100, height: 50}} source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${image.data}`}}/>
```

Please replace image.data with the binary data you are receiving.