# how to get images from mongo with axios and display them with react

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, axios, multer

The server route:

```
router.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
const image = await Image.findOne({})

res.json(image)
})
```

Axios:

```
const image = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/images/images")
setAvailableFile(image.data.img.data)
```

if console.log availableFile i get:

```
img:
   contentType: "image/jpeg"
   data: {type: "Buffer", data: Array(11615)}
   __proto__: Object
   name: "download.jpg"
   __v: 0
   _id: "5feb25dff4b7b43344a92952"
```

react:

```
  <div>
      {availableFile && availableFile.data}
  </div>
```

now the thing is, when i try to display the image i get something like:

255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,132,0,9,6,7,16,16,15,21,16,15,15,16,21,16....

any ideas?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out, i'll share the solution. to make this work i needed to do 2 things:

1. the first one is what @Viet said.
2. and then i need to add {image.img.data.toString('base64')} to the get request:

   ```
   router.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
         const image = await Image.findOne({})

         res.json(image.img.data.toString('base64'))
   })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if the binary data is represented as a base64 string:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${availableFile.data}`} />
```

Ref: [How to display binary data as image in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395034/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-in-react)

Why are you using div to display an image though?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! but i am not sure how i can implement this on my code..

Comment: see the answer here to convert binary data to base64 first