# My response contains an png, how can I display the image in react since its not a url?

Tags: reactjs, image, png

I have a response containing an image in png format,but I am unable to display it in react since it is not a url
[pic of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSFGx.png)

does anyone know how I can convert this png into a URL so I can insert it into my src of img tag?

Comment: "I have a response containing an image in png format" — No, you don't. You have a response containing a string which appears to be the file name of an image.

Comment: "does anyone know how I can convert this png into a URL" — No. Consult the API documentation for that.

Comment: lol @ Quentin's temper

Answer (score 22):

This is something I did when I was doing a similar thing in a React project.

## 1) Assuming the following:

- The response that we get from the API is not BASE64 encoded
- The responseType is not specified in the request
- A png is the response

The response data will look like this :
[image]

With characters that does not look friendly.

## 2) With changed responseType

- Set **responseType: "arraybuffer"** in the request

The response will now have arrayBuffer in data of the response

[image]

The response can then be converted to base64 by

```
let base64ImageString = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
```

If you want to display it on an img tag, then
prepend *data:image/png;base64,* to the Base64 string

```
let srcValue = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64ImageString
```

> **But in your case, it seems like you are only getting the file name as a string and not the file itself.**

Comment: how do I change response type?? thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 ...  specify it in the configuration that is sent alongside the http request

Answer (score 1):

Why not treat imege you need as Bese64 string? 
If you're able to convert you png image to a Base64 string (server side obviously) you can easily use it in img tag as src attribute value.

Comment: i don't have access to the backend,is there a way to do this in the frontend?

Comment: If your response include exactly what you've posted in the attached image in your question, 'cover_imag' attribute rappresents just a string value. Any kind of image source data has provided. So, there's no way to use it as img tag source value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image inside your application ( assets folder or whatever ) you could display it like that

```
<img src={`assets/${coverImage}`}>
```

Else The image should be sent from the API in the base64 format and then you could simply display it like that.

```
data = "base64 image"
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

same in my case. `"react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.2",` 
my response contains png image(no URL, no base64),
I converted my response into base64 as below,

```
const makeApiRequest = async()=>{
    try {
        const response = await apiCaller('ProfileImage',{"thisID": "ABCD","thatID": "1234"})
        if(response.status === 200){
            const dataResponse = await response.blob()
            let blob = new Blob([dataResponse], { type: "text/plain" });
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function () {
               var base64String = reader.result; 
               setImageFromAPI(base64String.substr(base64String.indexOf(', ') + 1)); //Setting response to hook
            }
        }else{
            console.log(response.status)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("components/profile/ProfileTimeline.js:-",error)
    }
}
```

But when I use it in my image tag its shows no image, and i don't know why

```
<Image  source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${imagefromAPI}`}}  style={{width:100, height:100}} resizeMode="cover" />
```