# Upload a file to my github repo from postman

Tags: github, postman

I would like to upload a file to my Github repo from Postman. What I have tried is:

1. Generate token from PAT: https://github.com/settings/tokens.
2. Method PUT URL: https://github.com/username/test2/info/lfs/objects/cd00e292c5970d3c5e2f0ffa5171e555bc46bfc4faddfb4a418b6840b86e79a2
3. Body is a 1 MB file.

I am receiving the following error: Your browser did something unexpected. Please contact us if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API Reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#example-input) you can't simply `PUT` a file to that URL.  Rather, you need to encode the file as Base64, and put it within a `JSON` object with the following inputs:

```
{
  "message": "my commit message",
  "committer": {
    "name": "Scott Chacon",
    "email": "schacon@gmail.com"
  },
  "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
}
```

Comment: @ParinSanghavi take a look at this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for

Comment: Can you explain the entire process with steps? I should probably learn about REST sometime.

Comment: @ParinSanghavi you mean of encoding in Base64? Or uploading a file to github?

Comment: @ParinSanghavi you will need to read the data in from a datafile (https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files), use Javascript to base64 encode it, and then `PUT` it using the JSON format I described above.