# Security vulnerabilities involved with Base64 encoded url

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web, urlencode

I have an API when trying to access it through a web application, I am making ajax `get` and `post` requests.

As I am new to this, I am wondering what the security concerns are with respect to the content type.

Right now I know of two content types I can POST the data as:

- Base64enoded URL.
- JSON

If I am passing the data as encoded URL, the data will appear in the query string.

Even if Base64encoded wouldn't it be a bad way of passing sensitive information?

I read several articles and most of them said JSON or URL encoded wouldn't matter much in terms of security.

What are the security breaches that I must be concerned with when looking at the content type used to pass data between the application and the API?

Comment: Is the data really in the URL or is it just URL-encoded base64-encoded data in the body of the POST request?

Comment: Treat base64 encoding/decoding as pretty much plain text. And just because you're base64 decoding/encoding something doesn't mean you need to pass it via query string. You can still POST it, same as json.

Comment: Base64 encoded strings can be decoded easily, if you want to secure data, use some cryptography tool to encode  data before transmitting.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts 

The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded,

I checked with the browser Dev tools, and the encoded data appears in the url, my thought is, using a basic Base64 encoding ,wouldn't it be very easy to just decode the data from the url!!?:)

Comment: This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: @FrankerZ Hi,This might be the X/Y type of question;I am learning php by decoding the code of an opensource application.Here they have used application/x-www-form-urlencoded to send data to an API.Since I am learning,my question is isnt this a security risk!! I read a few articles and everywhere it says;Sending as JSON or in query string doesnt affect security much,it is an entirely different thing!!So I have taken to stackoverflow hoping to be pointed in the right direction:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Base64Encode/Decode` is **not** developed to `encrypt` or `transfer` data securely. Can use `Base64` to transfer `string` contains special characters **without** interrupt the protocol or function [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)

In your case, you should use `SSL` to make a **secure** & **encrypted** connection between `server` & `client`.

And also you can use the `RSA Encryption` method to encrypt your data, Before sending it. (SSL uses this algorithm)

When you come to `API`, There is another point `(Sniffing Security)`. You should provide a security layer to protect your data from being modified in the middle way. You can use [HMAC](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/hmac/) to verify the data.

These are very common security tips. You can find more by googling the following keywords.
`HMAC`, `Hash`, `RSA Encryption`, `SSL Certificate`