# Failing to open image file that has been saved as raw data, sent from client

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here are the steps my application is doing:

1. User uploads an image (.PNG) file in the browser.
2. Browser sends the raw image data to my server.
3. The server then saves the file in my file system.

**The problem is that my file system complains that the file is not a PNG file when I try to open it.**

I'm trying to localize where the problem occurs without success. When I look at the file data using VIM it looks the same to me, with the same number of lines and the file contents both start with:

```
<89>PNG^M
 ^Z
 ^@^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^BD^@^@^@Î^H^B^@^@^@P6<8a><9a>^@^@^@^CsBIT^H^H^HÛáOà^  ^@^@_zTXtRaw profile type APP1^@^@^H<99>ãJOÍK-ÊLV((ÊOËÌIåR^@^Cc^S.   ^SK^SK£D^C^C^C^K^C^H04006^D<92>F@          
...
```

However, the file sizes are different, with the file I'm writing from my server being larger. So obviously they are different in some way.

I tried doing `diff file1 file2` in the command line and it just gives me `binary files differ` without showing me the difference... ?? Strange.

So I'm currently confused about how the files differ, and where in my code this difference gets introduced...

I feel I'm missing some crucial knowledge about how some things work here under the hood, and I would very much appreciate if someone smarter than me could help me out here.

**Code**

Client:

```
<input id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
<label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <Button/>
</label>

 function handleChange(event: any) {
        if (!event.target.files[0]) return

        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            const instance = axios.create({
                baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
                timeout: 5000,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
            instance.post(
                'image',
                JSON.stringify({
                    imageData: e.target.result.toString()
                })
            ).then(result => {
                console.log(result)
            })
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
}
```

Server:

```
app.post(`http://localhost:3000/image`, (req, res) => {
   fs.writeFile('img.png', req.body.imageData, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
   })
})
```

**EDIT:** 
I made it work by sending the image content to the server as a dataUrl instead, using `reader.readAsDataUrl()`. This encodes the image data as a Base64 string, which seems like a common practice. However, I'm still curious why sending the raw data doesn't work.

Comment: lot of string-ing going on in there. Do you need to call .toString() even with the JSON.stringify?

Comment: Valid point, however I tried removing it but with the same result...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Formidable to handle files in nodejs easily. Good to hear that you got it running already. I hope this helps to someone else. [this covers some basics](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp)
and yes another approach is  to encode to Base64 and decode back to a file from the server side. cheers
        var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var formidable = require('formidable');
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
      res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      res.write('<input type="submit">');
      res.write('</form>');
      res.end()
    });
    router.post(`/fileupload`, (req, res) => {
      var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        var newpath = './public/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
          res.end();
        });
      });
    })
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The reason for the problem was that I was sending the image binary data over http which can corrupt the data.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201510/6017605

Since base64 encodes it as text, it can safely be transmitted.

This also helped me understand the problem: https://www.jscape.com/blog/ftp-binary-and-ascii-transfer-types-and-the-case-of-corrupt-files