# How to convert a test message to an integer number to produce ciphertext in RSA

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, rsa, converters

The function `ConvertToInt(message)` should convert a text message to an integer number so ciphertext in RSA can be produced using the formula M^e mod n. Here M is the message that must be encoded into a single number. Instead, my following function ConvertToInt returns an array with elements each of which is the ASCII value of the characters. So the result becomes a character by character encryption instead of a string.

Which is the proper way to convert the message to an integer and calculate the proper RSA encrypted result?

Here is my code:

```
def ConvertToInt(message):
    l = len(message)
    arra = []
    i = 0
    while(i<l):
        j=ord(message[i])
        arra.append(j)
        i += 1
    return arra

def mod_ex(b, k, m):

    i = 1
    j = 0
    while(j<=k):
        b = (b*i) % m
        i = b
        j += 1
    return b
def PowMod(s,modulo,exponent):

    bin_e = bin(exponent)
    bin_e = bin_e [::-1]
    ln = len(bin_e)
    result = 1
    slen = len(s)
    for i in range(0,slen,+1):
        for j in range(0,ln-2,+1):
            if(bin_e[j]=='1'):
                result *= mod_ex(s[i],j,modulo)
        s[i] = result%modulo
        result = 1
    return s

def Encrypt(message, modulo, exponent):

  s = ConvertToInt(message)
  return PowMod(s, modulo, exponent)

x = Encrypt("Aa",473,17)
print(x)
```

Comment: "and I got this wrong" is not a proper error, what problem do you experience?

Comment: ops! I should clear it more.. What is the proper way of encoding text messages in case of RSA encryption so as to apply M^e mod n? and what would be the output looks like in integer after encryption. I desperately needed an example of input-output so to do like that..

Comment: If my input is "Attack" the array would return "285, 19, 19, 213, ...." But if I return this as a string "2851919213...." then it wouldn't be possible to decrypt. But if I return as "285019019213.." now I can decrypt (n-1 = 472 = 3, take 3 by 3 digits to decrypt)  But again if n is too large there is lots of 0 in the encrypted string. So what is the proper way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ConvertToInt function that effectively calculated a number out of a string which can be used in RSA Encryption, cz RSA encryption must need a number to operate.

```
def ConvertToInt(message):
grd = 1
num = 0
message = message [::-1]
for i in range(0,len(message),+1):
    num = num+ord(message[i])*grd
    grd *= 256
return num
```

Get the full RSA Code in python here:

- https://github.com/Sazzad-Saju/RSA_Algorithm

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on your application. But, as we are using encryption for communicating often, it is better to use *Encoding* that is more compatible with communication systems. For example, ***[Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)*** is one of the popular encodings used for encryption schemes(either Symmetric or Asymmetric).