# atob() and btoa() use cases

Tags: javascript, base64, ascii

What are the use cases for `atob()` and `btoa()` other than when trying to prevent communication problems in information transfer?

I've researched this online, but I didn't find anything other than information transfer communication problems. This is the resource that I found: [atob() and btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [what is base 64 encoding used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for).

In particular, on the web, base-64 encoding is useful for contexts where binary data is forbidden, which includes much of HTML. For example, if you want to inline a PNG image file into a URL, for use in an `<img src>` for example, you can write `data:image/png;base64,...` where `...` is the base-64 encoding of the PNG file.  `btoa` is useful for generating such URLs, like so:

```js
const url = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(pngContent);
```